# No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.MetricsEndpoint'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I upgraded spring.version from 5.0.18.RELEASE to 5.3.21

and spring.boot.version from 2.1.18.RELEASE to 2.7.0

spring-boot-starter-actuator ${spring.boot.version}

In my Healthcheck class I use:

```
@Autowired private MetricsEndpoint metrics;
```

After upgrade I've got:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthcheck':
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'metrics'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.MetricsEndpoint' available: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. 
Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Why Spring doesn't see org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.MetricsEndpoint ?

Comment: Don't manage spring... Only manage Spring Boot. Next to that you are upgrading 6 versions, I suggest to read the upgrade guides for each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2.1.18.RELEASE to 2.7.0 is an enormous jump, so as the comment says I'd suggest checking the upgrade guide carefully.

Nonetheless, you need to expose the metrics endpoint in your config, which will create the bean.

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: metrics
```

Comment: Added to my application.properties management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=metrics but it didn't work.
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=* didn't help either

Comment: I made such a big jump because previous versions are marked as containing vulnerabilities
Аdvise me to upgrade versions of spring boot gradually, for example, first to 2.2.0 and try to run the project on each version?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice that the management.endpoints.web.exposure.exclude=* was written in application.properties. After I excluded it, your solution helped.